# Barbell Curl Form

Tags: weightlifting

I've recently began lifting weights again. When doing curls, whether it's barbell or dumbbell, my right elbow sometimes likes to try and pull away and point out to my side, once fatigue starts to set in.

What is the cause of this? I always thought my right bicep was a bit stronger than my left, but my only guess is this happens because of bicep weakness.

The only other factor I can think of is I've had quite a few right shoulder dislocations in the past, and had my labrum repaired almost four years ago. Maybe a weaker shoulder could cause this?

Comment: This type of issue might be better reserved for an orthopedic to troubleshoot as far as how your shoulder is concerned. I know that doesn't help much, but there are many things to consider with a shoulder injury.  The shoulder is a very complicated joint and also the most versatile joint in the human body.  Further, the biceps tendon intersects with several of tendons and connective tissue in the shoulder complex.  However, it is possible that this is a strength asymmetry issue between your biceps.  Please consult a doctor to rule out the aforementioned or venture on at your own risk.

Answer (score -1):

As @Sean_Perkins said, see a medical professional before making any decisions. It's pretty common for form in general to start breaking down on fatigue. If you're worried about injuries (please run this by a properly licensed medical professional), use cable machines with light weight and focus on the peak contraction.  Heavier dumbbells might be harder to control and could further risk injury. Also try working out your forearms/grip strength because often times that's what gives out before our biceps leading to the form break down.